# Need help to write a Java math formula for this assignment

Tags: java, formula

Hi I'm in my 2nd week of Java and I was assigned a mah worksheet formula, but I don't know how to do it and I really need help.
The question is: Write a formula, which will add 5 the the cube of double t times double n and assign it to double X.

what I have so far

```
X= Math.cube(t*n)+5;
```

I feel like I did his wrong since I hardly understand how to do it.

Comment: Java is not Javascript.

Comment: Like I said its my 2nd week I still don't understand things, but thank you.

Comment: don't let these guys (or girls) discourage you, they can be overly harsh

Comment: Ask your teacher for help and understanding not the internet. That's what teachers are paid for after all.

Comment: @Luminous <sarcasm>So harsh!  Why can't you be "kind" like @godmode?</sarcasm>

Comment: Luminous it's an online class, and I have already emailed the teacher 3 days ago and still had no reply so I came here for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... add 5 ***to*** the cube of double t times double n and assign it to double X.

It's ambiguous in that it doesn't really specify whether it's:

- `(the cube of t) times (n)`; or
- `the cube of (t times n)`<sup>1</sup>.

So you'll be stuck with one of:

```
X = Math.pow(t,3) * n + 5
X = Math.pow(t*n,3) + 5
```

I haven't looked deeply at the changes in Java 8 by the way but I'm pretty certain there's no `Math.cube()` in older iterations at least. Hence the use of `Math.pow()`.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is why computer languages are far superior to natural ones. If only my wife and kids spoke C, I'd be a happy man :-)

Comment: "... and assign it to double X". I think double here (and in previous occurrences) is just a type of variable.

Comment: @Anton, yeah, realised not that long ago that it was the type rather than "two times". Fixed now.